# Can there be a PHD thesis without using SPSS?

Tags: statistics

I am MA degree student. I consider to do a phd. But I have some worries. First, I do not want to take any kind of statistics course.
Second I dont want to use the SPSS programme at all in my dissertation. Do you think with these conditions, can I do a phd.
Or are these two a must?
Please help me it is very much confusing me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 6):

> MA degree student

In *what*?

> First, I do not want to take any kind of statistics course.

Taking statistics is not inherently part of a PhD program. You could, for example, get your doctoral degree in English focusing on Utopian Fiction. Or in Architecture, focusing on 16th century French Cathedrals.

> Second I dont want to use the SPSS programme at all in my dissertation.

There are myriad ways to do statistics - SPSS is by no means the only way to do statistics.

However, like Austin Henley, I find your question somewhat puzzling. What gave you the impression that these things *were* necessary? What field are you actually considering working in - because the answer will vary wildly by field. And along the same lines of his question, why are you approaching your search starting with "I don't want to do statistics, and I *definitely* don't want to use a particular software package"? If answering what you're actually interested in required statistics, wouldn't you want to be able to get at it the best way possible?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your field and projects. There are plenty of dissertations out there that don't use any statistics.

Statistics is just a tool. Not taking a course on the subject may not be an issue. Not using a particular piece of software (SPSS) may not be an issue. Neither of these were required for me in computer science.

But to go into a PhD program with this type of mindset seems really strange to me. If statistics is the right tool for you to use, then why wouldn't you use it? Considering all the other hurdles with doing a PhD, learning the necessary knowledge of statistics will likely be very, very minor.